# Python Count function not increasing in tutorial video

Tags: python

I am just learning python and am following a video course. I copied an example from the video, but the loop isn't working and being new I can't figure out why. 
The only change I've made is to add print statements to see what's happening.
When I run it, both printing the count and the final print statement return 0, but it should be 4.

Can anyone shed some light on what's wrong with it?

```
def countChar(ch, teststring):
    count = 0
    print(ch)
    print(teststring)
    print(len(teststring))
    for i in range(len(teststring)):
        print(i)
        if teststring[i] == ch:
            count += 1
            print(count)
        return count

print(countChar('e', "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"))
```

Result

```
e
the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog
44
0
0
```

Comment: You are returning too early. Move return statement as it is over-indented

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `return count` statement is inside the for loop. You want to put it outside the for loop, but inside the function `countChar`. Simply do this to your code:

```
def countChar(ch, teststring):
    count = 0
    print(ch)
    print(teststring)
    print(len(teststring))
    for i in range(len(teststring)):
        print(i)
        if teststring[i] == ch:
            count += 1
            print(count)
    return count

print(countChar('e', "the quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog"))
```

Comment: Thank you! I was sure I indented everything as per the video. But I must have made the mistake, can't imagine they'd leave that in!

Answer (score 0):

`return count` is inside for-loop, indent it to same level as for is.